# Loss files haven't committed after sync using github gui client

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I am working with my classmates , and I write a few codes today . After click sync , all of my files written recently are missing . Is there a way to recover them ?

Answer (score 0):

When you made a commit it will probably viewable via console and

```
git reflog
```

From there you can google how to reset via reflog.

If you did not commit I am not sure if someone can help you.

Comment: I didn't make a comment , I thought sync is safe and I was not ready to commit my changes yet.

Comment: OK, yes, Sync is safe. What does it show when you click `Changes`?

Comment: I changed repo and pressed Sync. My local changes are still there. Can someone else help?